# Why won't my paragraph indent like the one above it

Tags: html

Can anyone tell me why my code wont indent like the paragraph above it?

I need the line that says "-Justin Reynolds" to be indented just like the one above it.

```html
<hr>
<section>

  <blockquote>I was struggling to lose weight after the birth of my second child. My friend recommended NewYou, and after the first three months I had lost 30 pounds. Thanks to the personal attention from their trainers and counselors, I've been able to keep the
    weight off for two years. I'm in the best shape of my life!</blockquote>

  <cite>&#8212;Justine Reynolds, Cleveland </cite> 

  <hr>
  <h3>Call today to speak to one of our certified fitness specialists.</h3>


</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `<cite>` inside the blockquote and create new lines with `<br>`

```html
<hr>
<section>

  <blockquote>I was struggling to lose weight after the birth of my second child. My friend recommended NewYou, and after the first three months I had lost 30 pounds. Thanks to the personal attention from their trainers and counselors, I've been able to keep the weight off for two years. I'm in the best shape of my life!

    <br>
    <br>
    <cite>&#8212;Justine Reynolds, Cleveland </cite>
  </blockquote>



  <hr>
  <h3>Call today to speak to one of our certified fitness specialists.</h3>


</section>
```

Or use CSS to move the `<cite>` left to align it with the blockquote

```css
cite {
  margin-left:40px;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<section>

  <blockquote>I was struggling to lose weight after the birth of my second child. My friend recommended NewYou, and after the first three months I had lost 30 pounds. Thanks to the personal attention from their trainers and counselors, I've been able to keep the weight off for two years. I'm in the best shape of my life!
  </blockquote>

  <cite>&#8212;Justine Reynolds, Cleveland </cite>

  <hr>
  <h3>Call today to speak to one of our certified fitness specialists.</h3>


</section>
```

Comment: First option is batter then second. Good Answer.

Comment: Ahh thats how you do it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Place the `Justine Reynolds....` line inside block quote after a line break

```html
<hr>
<section>

  <blockquote>I was struggling to lose weight after the birth of my second child. My friend recommended NewYou, and after the first three months I had lost 30 pounds. Thanks to the personal attention from their trainers and counselors, I've been able to keep the
    weight off for two years. I'm in the best shape of my life!
    <br>
    <cite>&#8212;Justine Reynolds, Cleveland </cite> 

  </blockquote>


  <hr>
  <h3>Call today to speak to one of our certified fitness specialists.</h3>


</section>
```